# HTML5 Geolocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I use this to geolocate the user and I need the values of `currentLat` and `currentLon` stored in a var:

```
    <script>  

  window.onload = function() {
    var startPos;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        startPos = position;
        document.getElementById("currentLat").innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("currentLon").innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
      });
    }
  };

</script>
```

I need those values in here:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=my_key&radius_units=km&radius=5&lat= XXX &lon= XXX &jsoncallback=?
```

How do I get the values through jQuery and put them in the URL immediately? What's the quickest way?

---

Thanks @Manuel but I have used it like this first as I don't need the error function, just to keep it simple so I can understand it but doesn't work?!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var JSONURL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=my_key&format=json&privacy_filter=1&media=photos&tag=london&minwidth=700&has_geo=1&accuracy=11&content_type=1&extras=geo,owner_name,url_m&page=1&radius_units=km&radius=5&"+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&jsoncallback=?";
  jQuery.getJSON( JSONURL, getJSONimages);
  function getJSONimages(data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
    var itemTitle = item.title;
                }); 
    $('#slideshow').html(htmlString);
    $('#slideshow').slideshow({
                timeout: 3000,
                type: 'random',
                fadetime: 2000
            });   
  } }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `var url` you'll get find the url with the lat an lon filled in

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    var url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=my_key&radius_units=km&radius=5&lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+'&jsoncallback=?';
    // console.log(url);
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong: ", error);
});
```